# how to use an aggregate on pandas df column and retain original df

Tags: python, pandas

I want to apply an aggregate to the pet age column, but retain the original df columns that disappear when this agg is applied. From the image, How do I bring the other columns to the resulting df when aggregate is applied.

I could also convert the other columns to numeric type, or merge this with the original?  Thanks!

[image]

Comment: You aren't showing the columns, what do you want to do with the multiple values in the other columns? Posting an image isn't helpful because it is hard to reproduce.

Comment: As long as the other columns don't destroy your grouping, you can just put them inside of `groupby`

Comment: Thanks guys! The other columns names `user_id sign_in_count species_cd age_last_login age_of_account subscription_age` . I would like to just leave the values as they are, but apply the agg to pet_age. I tried putting int he groupby like ```
merge.groupby('user_id','sign_in_count', 'species_cd', 'age_last_login', 'age_of_account', 'subscription_age').mean()```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) for inline aggregation or any group-specific computations that returns a like-indexed object:

```
merge['pet_age_group_mean'] = merge.groupby('user_id')['pet_age'].transform('mean')
```